# Erro 404 Tomcat

Tags: java-ee, maven

Estou começando com Maven, coloquei as dependências que quero no `pom.xml` e criei uma pagina `xhtml` pra testar porém da erro 404: `The requested resource is not available.`
No console não aparece  nada, fica em branco. Alguém sabe aonde estou errando?

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.sistema</groupId>
    <artifactId>PedidoVenda</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEnconding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEnconding>
    </properties>



    <!-- Implementação do JSF 2.2 -->
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Implementação do Primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>PedidoVenda</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Poste o seu arquivo pom.xml.

Comment: pronto, coloquei o pom na pergunta

Comment: Resolvi o problema tinha 2 servidores e o projeto estava nos dois, retirei ele do servidor do `OpenShift` e funcionou